# JSON output in Jersey 2.x fails

Tags: java, json, jersey

I recently upgraded to Jersey 2.x and when I call this web service :

```
@GET
@Path("/mocks")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getIt() {
    List<Date> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Date());
    list.add(new Date());
    list.add(new Date());
    return Response.status(200).entity(list).build();
}
```

I get the following error message :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
```

The complete output follows here:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: 
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:391)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

I commented out the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and the same happened again. I then tried to add the following dependency but nothing changed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas on how to solve that ?

Comment: can you show your web.xml?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Jackson as your JSON provider, try to add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>[required-version]</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register `JacksonFeature` in your `Configurable`.

```
public class MyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyConfig() {

        register(JacksonFeature.class);

        ...
    }
}
```

MOXy media module is one of the modules where you don't need to explicitly register it's features (`MoxyJsonFeature`) in your client/server `Configurable` as this feature is automatically discovered and registered when you add `jersey-media-moxy` module to your class-path.

A manual registration of any other Jersey JSON provider feature disables the automated enabling and configuration of `MoxyJsonFeature`.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Jersey 2.9, automatic discovery is disabled, in order to enable it like in previous versions you need to add a dependency to jersey-metainf-services.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-metainf-services</artifactId>
  <version>your_version</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable your JSON support by downloading the following any jar & Placed it in WEB-INF/lib.

JSON-P (8.1.3), Jackson (8.1.4) or Jettison (8.1.5) or you can try this also if others are not working fine -- Genson https://code.google.com/p/genson/

Hope it helps !!